# Component.js: Why does "this.getRouter()" return undefined even though "routing" is configured in manifest.json?

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to navigate from my view 1 to view 2 using router in UI5.

But I am getting the following error in console:

> 2022-11-24 20:26:37.980600 Failed to load component for container content. Reason: TypeError: Cannot read properties of `undefined` (reading '`initialize`') - Component.js

My `Component.js`:

```js
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/UIComponent",
    "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel"
], function (UIComponent, JSONModel) {
    "use strict";
    return UIComponent.extend("zpractice.Component",{
        metadata: {
             manifest: "json"
        },
        init: function () {
            UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);
            // ...
            this.getRouter().initialize();
        }
    });
});
```

My `manifest.json`:

```json
{
  "version": "1.12.0",
  "sap.app": {
    "id": "zpractice",
    "type": "application",
    "applicationVersion": {
      "version": "1.0.0"
    }
  },
  "sap.ui": {
    "technology": "UI5",
    "deviceTypes": {
      "desktop": true,
      "tablet": true,
      "phone": true
    }
  },
  "sap.ui5": {
    "rootView": {
      "viewName": "zpractice.view.project",
      "type": "XML",
      "id": "myApp",
      "async": true
    },
    "dependencies": {
      "minUI5Version": "1.93",
      "libs": {
        "sap.ui.core": {},
        "sap.ui.layout": {},
        "sap.m": {},
        "sap.f": {}
      },
      "routing": {
        "config": {
          "routerClass": "sap.m.routing.Router",
          "type": "View",
          "viewType": "XML",
          "path": "zpractice.view.",
          "controlId": "myApp",
          "controlAggregation": "pages",
          "async": true
        },
        "routes": [
          {
            "pattern": "",
            "name": "project",
            "target": "project"
          },
          {
            "pattern": "flex",
            "name": "flex",
            "target": "flex"
          }
        ],
        "targets": {
          "project": {
            "id": "project",
            "name": "project"
          },
          "flex": {
            "id": "flex",
            "name": "flex"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to route through my "project" view to "flex" view, but router is not getting initialized!

I am using UI5 walkthrough step 30 as reference!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that your `routing` in the `manifest.json` is in the wrong section:

Before:

```json
...
   "dependencies": {
      "minUI5Version": "1.93",
      "libs": {
        "sap.ui.core": {},
        "sap.ui.layout": {},
        "sap.m": {},
        "sap.f": {}
      },
      // Here the "routing" is still in the node of the "dependencies".
      "routing": {
        "config": {
          "routerClass": "sap.m.routing.Router",
          "type": "View",
          "viewType": "XML",
          "path": "zpractice.view.",
          "controlId": "myApp",
          "controlAggregation": "pages",
          "async": true
        },
      }
    }
...
```

How it should be:

```json
...
   "dependencies": {
      "minUI5Version": "1.93",
      "libs": {
        "sap.ui.core": {},
        "sap.ui.layout": {},
        "sap.m": {},
        "sap.f": {}
      },
    },
    // Here the "routing" is now outside of the "dependencies".
    "routing": {
      "config": {
        "routerClass": "sap.m.routing.Router",
        "type": "View",
        "viewType": "XML",
        "path": "zpractice.view.",
        "controlId": "myApp",
        "controlAggregation": "pages",
        "async": true
       },
     }
...
```